SdkErrorMessage= curlCode: 18, Transferred a partil file
I try to create external table on s3 with starrock.I use below configurations.
create external table test 
(c_0 String,
c_1 String) 
engine =file
properties
(
"aws.s3.endpoint" = "***",
"path" = "s3://bucketname/prefix_name/",
"format"="parquet",
"aws.s3.access_key"="***",
"aws.s3.secret_key"="***",
"aws.s3.region"="***",
"aws.s3.use_aws_sdk_default_behaviour"="true"
)

then i get following error message:
ERROR 1064 (HY000) BE access s3 file failed SdkResponseCode=-1 SdkErrorType=99, SdkErrorMessage=curlCode: 18 Transferred file: file= s3://bucketname/prefix_name/parquetfilename
Want to read data from s3 using by starrock
